# Problema con UPDATE y ProgressBar Async C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, async-await

trabajo en un programa para actualizar precios (lo típico de la universidad) pero lo que quiero hacer es que mientras se haga un progressbar se ejecute una consulta(UPDATE) a el servidor

Habia leido en post aqui sobre async y await, lo intente pero me arrogo un error que espera un await..

> - $exception  {"Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'ProBarUpdate' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel
>     en que lo creó."} System.InvalidOperationException

Aqui es donde mando llamar a los procesos asincronos

```
private void BtnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                Task<bool> TBool = ProgressBar();

                Actualizar();

                bool boolR = await TBool;


            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

proceso del progress

```
public async Task<bool> ProgressBar()
        {
            ProBarUpdate.Visible = true;
            lblProgreso.Visible = true;

            ProBarUpdate.Minimum = 0;
            ProBarUpdate.Maximum = DataPrecios.Rows.Count;
            ProBarUpdate.Step = 1;

            for (int fila = 0; fila < DataPrecios.Rows.Count; fila++)
            {
                ProBarUpdate.Increment(fila);

                lblProgreso.Text = "Codigo Articulo: " + DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            if (ProBarUpdate.Value == DataPrecios.Rows.Count)
            {
                ProBarUpdate.Value = 0;
                ProBarUpdate.Visible = false;
                lblProgreso.Text = "";
                lblProgreso.Visible = false;

                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Datos Completados", "Actualizacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

y este es donde actualizo las tablas

```
public void Actualizar()
        {
            Funciones F = new Funciones();
            F.RespaldoArticulos();

            for (int fila = 0; fila < DataPrecios.Rows.Count; fila++)
            {
                string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                    string query = "UPDATE CatalogoArticulos SET PrecioSinIva=@nuevoPrecioSinIva, " +
                        "PorcMargenUtilidad=@nuevoMargen,PrecioActual=@nuevoPrecio, IvaEnDinero=@IvaEnDinero " +
                        "WHERE CodigoArticulo = @codigo";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuevoPrecioSinIva", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuevoMargen", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuevoPrecio", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IvaEnDinero", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells["IvaEnDinero"].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

                        try
                        {
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

entendí algo pero no se como hacer un asincrono dentro del proceso progressbar

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final de cuenta lo pude solucionar, no entendia muy bien pero despues de un tiempo logre hacerlo

```
        public async Task<int> Actualizar()
    {

        int i = 0;

        Funciones F = new Funciones();
        F.RespaldoArticulos();

        for (int fila = 0; fila < DataPrecios.Rows.Count; fila++)
        {
            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string query = "UPDATE CatalogoArticulos SET PrecioSinIva=@nuevoPrecioSinIva, " +
                    "PorcMargenUtilidad=@nuevoMargen,PrecioActual=@nuevoPrecio, IvaEnDinero=@IvaEnDinero " +
                    "WHERE CodigoArticulo = @codigo";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuevoPrecioSinIva", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuevoMargen", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuevoPrecio", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IvaEnDinero", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells["IvaEnDinero"].Value.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

                    try
                    {
                       i = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return i;
    }

    public async void ProgressBar()
    {
        ProBarUpdate.Visible = true;
        lblProgreso.Visible = true;

        ProBarUpdate.Minimum = 0;
        ProBarUpdate.Maximum = DataPrecios.Rows.Count;
        ProBarUpdate.Step = 1;

        for (int fila = 0; fila < DataPrecios.Rows.Count; fila++)
        {
            ProBarUpdate.Increment(fila);

            lblProgreso.Text = "Codigo Articulo: " + DataPrecios.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        }

        int i = await Actualizar();

        if (i == 1)
        {
            ProBarUpdate.Value = 0;
            ProBarUpdate.Visible = false;
            lblProgreso.Text = "";
            lblProgreso.Visible = false;

            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Datos Completados", "Actualizacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

este fue mi código al final me funciona no es como quisiera pero funciona, ahora solo al botón hay que mandar llamar la función y listo, dejo el código por si alguno quiere una idea se que se puede mejorar